# I would like to know what set these parts belong - Gold design brick, harpoon spikes, columns, and pink streamers

Tags: set-identification

Gold design brick, harpoon spikes, columns, and pink streamers.
Anyone know this?

[image: Gold design brick, harpoon spikes, columns, and pink streamers]

Answer (score 13):

That is from [Cinderella's Dream Castle (41154)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41154-1)

[image]

Set identified by unique combination of [Support 1 x 1 x 6 Solid Pillar](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43888#T=C) in Pearl Gold and [Brick 1 x 4](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3010&colorID=154&in=A) in Lavender color.